# How can i position DIVs according to their height and width?

Tags: css, html

How can i slide up cards(divs) in first column ? (so that it looks neat, as div heights are variable)
Is this the limitation of HTML box model, or is there any hackish techniques without using javascript.
I dont want hide these cards by making background color of body to match these cards.

for the below image's HTML i used float:left property to inline these divs.

[image: screenshot for div positioning]

Css class for the div is here

```
.test{
   background:grey;
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   margin:5px;
}
```

Adding more info.   I dont want to put these divs in two/three columns.
I am trying to implement like posts in Google Plus. any div may contain any height and width !!!HTML should automatically place divs without spaces.

I have created a fiddle for the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/Phkz6/

Comment: Looks like you have margins on some of those divs. Care to share some code?

Comment: Post your current HTML markup and CSS, preferably inside a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the `div`'s either side assumed the same height (whichever is larger)? For that, just use a `table`.

Comment: Floating is likely the solution, but there's no way to provide a specific solution without seeing the HTML and CSS markup.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using `inline-block` instead. This way you gain control of the `height` property.

Comment: when i use inline-block space will appear above, and neeto set vertical-align to top. space still exists !!

Comment: You have to set the height as such `height: 200px`. I updated your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

1. Split the content area into two columns (each with `display: inline-block` and a width)
2. Each post should have width ~= 95%
3. Small margin right on the left one

**Here's a jsfiddle showing you what I mean:** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MkQRj/3/)

Comment: Yes you are right but what i wanted is to not have columns, so when window width is available to fit three divs in a row/ or one div in row it positions automatically. (simply like just like Gplus posts)

Answer (score -1):

We obviously need code for more detail, but:

- Assuming you are using float:left or display:inline-block etc. you can try "vertical-align:top" on your items, sometimes it does the trick for a simple stack.
- Tables works best for a grid and your will have a very level row, but you will have a pretty "Spreadsheet-ish" look where cells look unevenly filled.
- Also Masonry / isotope would make a really cool and fairly simple addition to your plans.